# LINQ Distinct does not invoke IEquatable<T>.Equals

Tags: linq

I have a set of domain object, deriving from a base, where I've overridden `Equals`, `IEquatable<T>.Equals` and equality operators. I've successfully used `Contains`, but now I am trying to use `Distinct` differently. Here's look at a sample code:

```cs
var a = new Test { Id = 1 };
var a2 = new Test { Id = 1 };
var list = new List<Test> { a, a2 };

var distinct = list.Distinct().ToList(); // both objects, Equal implementations not called
var containsA = list.Contains(a); // true, Equal implementations called
var containsA2 = list.Contains(a); // true
var containsNewObjectWithSameId = list.Contains(new Test { Id = 1 }); // true

public class Test : IEquatable<Test>
{
    public int Id { get; init; }
    public bool Equals(Test other)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(null, other))
            return false;
        if (ReferenceEquals(this, other))
            return true;
        if (this.GetType() != other.GetType())
            return false;
        return this.Id == other.Id;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode() => base.GetHashCode + this.Id;
}
```

`Contains` finds matches, but `Distinct` is feeling very inclusive and keeps them both. From MS docs:

> The first search does not specify any equality comparer, which means FindFirst uses
> EqualityComparer.Default to determine equality of boxes. That in turn uses the implementation
> of the IEquatable.Equals method in the Box class.

What am I missing?

Comment: I can't reproduce this. With your exact code, just printing out `distinct.Count()` prints 1, not 2. Please provide a [mcve] that definitely demonstrates the problem.

Comment: LINQ nature is lazy execution, if you do not call materialization methods, like Count, ToList, First, etc. everything which do not return IEnumerable, it may not execute methods that you expect.

Comment: @JonSkeet I've edited the sample. It seems that the problem is with calling `base.GetHashCode`, as you are correct - by only using `this.Id` it works indeed.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv I know about deferred execution, but that's not it. I've added ToList.

Comment: Right, so basically the problem was that you now have an invalid `GetHashCode` implementation - it violates the requirement that two objects which compare equal *must* have the same hash code. That's nothing to do with LINQ really - other than that LINQ depends on the rules for GetHashCode and Equals. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.gethashcode?view=net-6.0. As a side note, you should really override Equals(object) as well.

Comment: @JonSkeet I guess that makes sense. However I am curious as to why it happens to work correctly with Contains. I am confident of this, as I've been using this faulty GetHashCode implementation for a while now.

Comment: @Alex: I suspect Contains is only using Equals - it only needs to test against each member of the collection once, so there's no benefit in using GetHashCode.

Comment: @JonSkeet okey, I got it. Do you want to write down an answer, or should I?

Comment: Feel free to do so yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @JonSkeet for your insight in the comments.

The problem in this case is the way I wrote my `GetHashCode` method. It has nothing to do with LINQ, as I originally thought.

### Explanation

`GetHashCode` has to be identical for objects that compare equally. In my case - since the base implementation of `object.Equals` only checks for reference equality and I am comparing two separate objects - *a* and *b*, their `base.GetHashCode` would result in different values, which in turn would render those two objects as not equal.

### Solution

In this case, simply returning the Id value is enough as is shown in MS docs:

> One of the simplest ways to compute a hash code for a numeric value that has the same or a smaller range than the Int32 type is to simply return that value.

So changing the above code sample like this:

```cs
public override int GetHashCode() => this.Id;
```

would solve the issue. Please keep in mind that if the value of `Id` is not unique, this will cause ill behavior. In such cases you'll need another property to check and you will have to compose `GetHashCode` from ALL those properties. For further info refer to [MS docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.gethashcode?view=net-6.0)